# Certbot renewal hook won't finish

Tags: lets-encrypt

I use a certificate from Lets Encrypt both in my Apache and Dovecot. Restarting the Apache process to pick up the new process already works, this seems to be embedded in certboy anywhere. But I struggle to restart Dovecot at the end of the process.

I've added a hook at `/etc/letsencrypt/renewal-hooks/deploy/dovecot.sh` with the following simple content:

```
#!/bin/sh
service dovecot restart
```

Using `sudo`, this script does what it should: restart the Dovecot service. Trying whether the hook works through `sudo certbot -vvv --force-renewal renew` is not successful: this works till the line `Running deploy-hook command: /etc/letsencrypt/renewal-hooks/deploy/dovecot.sh` is outputted after the certificate was exchanged, then certbot is stuck :(

`ps aux | grep dovecot` contains the following line and also shows that the server has in deed been restarted:

```
root      3979  0.0  0.0      0     0 pts/3    Z+   18:48   0:00 [dovecot.sh] <defunct>
```

Using `ctrl+c`, the following stacktrace is printed:

```
Exiting abnormally:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/certbot", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('certbot==0.21.1', 'console_scripts', 'certbot')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/main.py", line 1240, in main
    return config.func(config, plugins)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/main.py", line 1142, in renew
    renewal.handle_renewal_request(config)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/renewal.py", line 425, in handle_renewal_request
    main.renew_cert(lineage_config, plugins, renewal_candidate)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/main.py", line 1065, in renew_cert
    _get_and_save_cert(le_client, config, lineage=lineage)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/main.py", line 113, in _get_and_save_cert
    renewal.renew_cert(config, domains, le_client, lineage)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/renewal.py", line 310, in renew_cert
    hooks.renew_hook(config, domains, lineage.live_dir)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/hooks.py", line 187, in renew_hook
    _run_deploy_hook(hook, domains, lineage_path, config.dry_run)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/hooks.py", line 221, in _run_deploy_hook
    _run_hook(command)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/hooks.py", line 229, in _run_hook
    err, _ = execute(shell_cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/hooks.py", line 242, in execute
    out, err = cmd.communicate()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 801, in communicate
    stdout, stderr = self._communicate(input, endtime, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1446, in _communicate
    ready = selector.select(timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/selectors.py", line 376, in select
    fd_event_list = self._poll.poll(timeout)
KeyboardInterrupt
Please see the logfiles in /var/log/letsencrypt for more details.
```

My configuration:

- Debian 9.3 with latest updates
- certbot in version 0.21.1-1~bpo9+1

Comment: Someone at https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/5424 seems to have the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution has been posted at https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/5424#issuecomment-372126909: restarting dovecot holds stderr open, this blocks python. Changing the script in the following way solved my problem:

```
#!/bin/sh
service dovecot restart 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution I found out after some hours was finally the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
/<path-to-my-script>/<my-script>.sh &>/dev/null &
disown
```

Comment: did you mean `script`?